# Unable to display google font in 'light' weight

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I'm trying to use [Merriweather from Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather).

I'm able to use the *regular* and *bold* weights, but I cannot get the *light* weight to work.

In my `<head>` you can see that I am linking to all three weights:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

However in my css the following does not seem to use a lighter font weight:

```
font-weight:300
```

Here is a CodePen with this problem:
http://codepen.io/vivmaha/pen/XNLEoE

*Aside — I wanted to embed the snip directly into SO, but I needed codepen to link to the google font*

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? It looks fine for me (300 is lighter than 400).

Comment: I also see 300 as lighter than the other weights.

Comment: Latest chrome. Latest windows. 
Turns  out that the error was that I had the font installed on my OS with just one weight. The browser used my OS-installed font which didn't have the light weight. I uninstalled the font from my OS and it looks lighter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was because I had the font installed on my local OS.
The browser used the font from the OS instead of google's servers.
However the OS font didn't have the light weight installed.